# Plotting a set in wxMaxima

Tags: maxima-software

I have to plot the graph of this set in wxMaxima, but no manual has helped me. I've only been able to plot functions.

$$ {(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}: x\in[0,2]\wedge y\in[0,4]} $$

I tried this, which obviously did not work out

```
plot2d(x,y, [x,0,2], [y,0,4]);
```

Was my question clear? Could you give a light?

Comment: What do you mean by plot sets? You mean the area of $[0,2]\times[0,4]$?

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Answer (score 0):

Draw a rectangle in a diagram, plot2d won't let you plot a function of $y$.

`qdraw(xrange(0,10), yrange(0,10), rect(0,0,2,4,lc([line_color]), lw([line_thickness]),fill([fill_color])))`

The last 3 arguments are optional with default of `blue, 3, no color`

---

Edit:

If you have some set of with the boundaries of $f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_n(x)$ you had the right way of thinking, plot the functions and fill the area between them, the problem is that you can only plot functions of $x$, and the sides, $y\in [0,4]$, are a functions of $y$, not of $x$. So you draw a line instead of plot a function, in this case we can just take rectangle over that region.